# Acquire lock before attribute read/write on CPython C extension type

Tags: python, c, multithreading, cpython

I'm writing a multithreaded C extension for CPython. I have POD which is made thread safe with a simple [libuv rwlock](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/threading.html#read-write-locks). I'd like to wrap this so it can be allocated and the data accessed from Python via simple `PyMemberDef`'s. My question is, is it sufficient to just acquire/release the lock in `getattro` and `setattro` or am I missing something? I'm new to the CPython API so feel free to recommend a different approach entirely.

Simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <uv.h>

typedef struct Pod_s {
  uv_rwlock_t lock;
  int number;
} Pod;

typedef struct PyPod_s {
    PyObject_HEAD
    Pod pod;
} PyPod;

static PyMemberDef[] PyPod_members = {
  {"number", T_INT, offsetof(PyPod, pod) + offsetof(Pod, number)},
  {0},
};

static PyObject *PyPod_new(PyTypeObject *type, PyObject *args, PyObject *kwds) {
  PyPod *self;
  self = (PyPod *) type->tp_alloc(type, 0);
  if(self != NULL)
    uv_rwlock_init(&self->pod.lock);  // In real life this would be error-checked
  return (PyObject *) self;
}

// Is this getattro/setattro safe?
static PyObject *PyPod_getattro(PyObject *self, PyObject *attr) {
  PyPod *pypod = (PyPod *) self;
  uv_rwlock_rdlock(&pypod->pod.lock);
  PyObject *ret = PyObject_GenericGetAttr(self, attr);
  uv_rwlock_rdunlock(&pypod->pod.lock);
  return ret;
}

static int PyPod_setattro(PyObject *self, PyObject *attr, PyObject *value) {
  PyPod *pypod = (PyPod *) self;
  uv_rwlock_wrlock(&pypod->pod.lock);
  int ret = PyObject_GenericSetAttr(self, attr, value);
  uv_rwlock_wrunlock(&pypod->pod.lock);
  return ret;
}

static PyTypeObject PyPodType = {
  PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
  .tp_name = "PodModule.Pod",
  .tp_basicsize = sizeof(PyPod),
  .tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT,
  .tp_new = PyPod_new,
  .tp_members = PyPod_members,
  .tp_getattro = PyPod_getattro,
  .tp_setattro = PyPod_setattro,
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else tries to do this: Yep, this is thread safe *for your C code*.

The un-asked question here is what about the Python interpreter? If only the main thread (the interpreter that called into your extension) ever calls back into/returns to the interpreter, then you don't have anything to worry about.

If however threads spawned in your C extension have the ability to call into the interpreter, you need to consider the GIL. First release the GIL and acquire the main thread's state with `PyEval_SaveThread()`. Then use the `interp *` stored in the thread state to spin up new thread states with `PyThreadState_New(interp)`, one for each thread you intend to create in C. Finally, before calling back into the Python interpreter, acquire the GIL with `PyEval_RestoreThread(tstate)`, call the Python, and release it with `PyEval_SaveThread()` when you're done.